# DB2 SQL Anything left of a /

Tags: sql, db2

I've been working on this for days and can't seem to work it out.  Basically I need return digits from a field before there is a forward slash.  e.g. if the field was 1234/TEXT I want to return 1234.  I can't just use left fieldname 4 as the digits vary in left e.g. 12345/TEXT, so it needs to be anything left of the forward slash.  Now in the World of MS Access, it is something like this - and it works

```
Left(TABLE!FIELD,InStr(1,TABLE!FIELD,"/")-1)
```

However, how do I convert this to be used in an IBM\DB2 system?  The DB2 SQL seems somewhat different to 'normal' SQL.

Thanks!

Comment: You're calling MS Access "normal SQL"? In normal SQL you'd reference a table column as `TABLENAME.COLUMNNAME`, not `TABLE!FIELD`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than INSTR, maybe LOCATE

LOCATE(char, string)

char is the search term
string is the string being searched

Comment: The `INSTR` function is available in recent DB2 versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by combining LOCATE with SUBSTR;

[Locate information](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_locate.html)

[Substring information](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_substr.html)

Cheat sheet (for this example);

```
SUBSTRING('FIELD','START POSITION', 'LENGTH')
LOCATE('SEARCH STRING', 'SOURCE STRING')
```

SUBSTRING lets you retrieve specific characters from a string, i.e.;

```
AFIELD = 'Hello'
SUBSTRING(AFIELD,4,2)
```

Result = 'lo' (position 4 and 5 of Hello)

LOCATE returns the position of the first character of the search string it finds as a number, i.e.;

```
AFIELD = 'Hello'
LOCATE('ello', AFIELD)
```

Result = 2 (it starts at position 2)

So you can combine these to do what you want, example;

XTABLE has 1 column called ACOL with the following values in it;

```
123467/ABCD 
1321/ABDD   
1123467/ABCD
```

To just retrieve the numbers;

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ACOL,1, LOCATE('/',ACOL)-1)
FROM XRDK/XTABLE
```

Result;

```
123467
1321
1123467
```

What are we doing?

```
SUBSTRING(
ACOL,
1, 
LOCATE('/',ACOL)-1
)

SUBSTRING(
Field ACOL, 
Starting at position 1, 
Length; using locate set this to where I find a '/' and subtract 1 from the 
resulting postion (without the -1 you'd have the / on the end)
)
```

Comment: Just noticed that this was asked in 2014, oops - hope you worked it out in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST (ROUND(COLUMN,2) AS DECIMAL(6,2)), 0, locate('/',CAST (ROUND(COLUMN,2) AS DECIMAL(6,2))))
FROM TABLE
```